# Getting error "could not find declaration file for module ..." in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I generally use *npm* install to build node_modules. But for some reasons I removed node_modules folder, updated the node to v12.8.1 and did yarn install.

Then on I am getting the below errors.

1. **Module not found**. although those modules are present in the node_modules.
2. **could not find declaration files...** although we are not using typescript in the project.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `package-lock.json`, `yarn-lock.json` files and `node_modules` folder. Again run `npm install` and check whether error persists.

Comment: I tried them. Still not working. Thanks